# Old PC Upgrade Recommendations

Tags: motherboard

I am upgrading a 2005 built computer running Windows XP (I know!).

I can not determine two things:

1. The exact make model and form factor of the motherboard. It seems to be nForce motherboard with 939 socket from what I could gather. How can I find out more about the motherboard?
2. Which processor, RAM and Motherboard should I upgrade this computer to?

```
System:    Host: linux Kernel: 5.4.53 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: JWM 2.4.0 dm: xinit  
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: N/A model: nForce serial: N/A BIOS: Phoenix v: 6.00 PG date: 09/13/2003 
CPU:       Topology: Single Core model: AMD Athlon 64 3200+ bits: 64 type: UP arch: K8 rev: 8 L1 cache: 128 KiB 
           L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 bogomips: 3989 
           Speed: 2000 MHz min/max: 800/2000 MHz Core speed (MHz): 1: 2000 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA NV43 [GeForce 6600 GT] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 02:00.0 
           chip ID: 10de:00f1 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nouveau compositor: picom resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NV43 v: 2.1 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA nForce3 Audio vendor: Biostar Microtech Intl Corp driver: snd_intel8x0 v: kernel bus ID: 00:06.0 
           chip ID: 10de:00da 
           Device-2: Creative Labs EMU10k2/CA0100/CA0102/CA10200 [Sound Blaster Audigy Series] driver: snd_emu10k1 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 01:08.0 chip ID: 1102:0004 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.53 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Biostar Microtech Intl Corp driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: c800 bus ID: 01:0d.0 chip ID: 10ec:8169 
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:e0:4c:b8:5b:fd 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 373.93 GiB used: 571.5 MiB (0.1%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD2500JB-00REA0 size: 232.89 GiB speed: <unknown> 
           serial: WD-WMANK5912436 rev: 0K20 scheme: MBR 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST3120022A size: 111.79 GiB speed: <unknown> serial: 5JT113FM rev: 3.06 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Cruzer Blade size: 29.25 GiB serial: 4C531001570928117361 rev: 1.00 
           scheme: MBR 
RAID:      Hardware-1: VIA VIA VT6420 SATA RAID Controller driver: sata_via v: 2.6 port: b000 bus ID: 01:0c.0 
           chip ID: 1106.3149 rev: 50 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 60.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 109 Uptime: 35m Memory: 985.2 MiB used: 270.9 MiB (27.5%) Init: SysVinit v: N/A runlevel: 35 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 running in: urxvt inxi: 3.0.38
```

```
lshw
    description: Desktop Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.3 dmi-2.3 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: nForce
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Phoenix Technologies, LTD
          physical id: 0
          version: 6.00 PG
          date: 09/13/2003
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3200+
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3200+
          slot: Socket A
          size: 2GHz
          capacity: 2GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 201MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl cpuid 3dnowprefetch vmmcall cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: Internal Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: External Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1a
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM
             product: None
             vendor: None
             physical id: 0
             serial: None
             slot: A0
             size: 1GiB
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM
             product: None
             vendor: None
             physical id: 1
             serial: None
             slot: A1
             size: 1GiB
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: nForce3 Host Bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: a4
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-amd64
          resources: irq:0 memory:e0000000-e7ffffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: nForce3 LPC Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: a6
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: nForce3 SMBus
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: a4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=nForce2_smbus latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:5 ioport:4c00(size=64) ioport:4c40(size=64)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: nForce3 USB 1.1
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: a5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:22 memory:ed003000-ed003fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: nForce3 USB 1.1
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: a5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:21 memory:ed004000-ed004fff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: nForce3 USB 2.0
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 2.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.2
             version: a2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: debug pm ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:20 memory:ed005000-ed0050ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: nForce3 Audio
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: a2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_intel8x0 latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
             resources: irq:22 ioport:d800(size=256) ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:ed001000-ed001fff
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: nForce3 IDE
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: a5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm isa_compat_mode pci_native_mode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pata_amd latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:f000(size=16)
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: nForce3 PCI Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
             version: a2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master
             resources: ioport:9000(size=16384) memory:eb000000-ecffffff memory:40000000-400fffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Multimedia audio controller
                product: EMU10k2/CA0100/CA0102/CA10200 [Sound Blaster Audigy Series]
                vendor: Creative Labs
                physical id: 8
                bus info: pci@0000:01:08.0
                version: 03
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_emu10k1 latency=32 maxlatency=20 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:16 ioport:9000(size=32)
           *-input
                description: Input device controller
                product: SB Audigy Game Port
                vendor: Creative Labs
                physical id: 8.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:08.1
                version: 03
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=Emu10k1_gameport latency=32
                resources: irq:0 ioport:9400(size=8)
           *-firewire:0
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: SB Audigy FireWire Port
                vendor: Creative Labs
                physical id: 8.2
                bus info: pci@0000:01:08.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=32 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:17 memory:ec005000-ec0057ff memory:ec000000-ec003fff
           *-firewire:1
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller
                vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
                physical id: b
                bus info: pci@0000:01:0b.0
                version: 80
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=32 maxlatency=32
                resources: irq:19 memory:ec004000-ec0047ff ioport:9800(size=128)
           *-raid
                description: RAID bus controller
                product: VIA VT6420 SATA RAID Controller
                vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
                physical id: c
                bus info: pci@0000:01:0c.0
                version: 50
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: raid pm bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=sata_via latency=32
                resources: irq:16 ioport:9c00(size=8) ioport:a000(size=4) ioport:a400(size=8) ioport:a800(size=4) ioport:ac00(size=16) ioport:b000(size=256) memory:40000000-4000ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: d
                bus info: pci@0000:01:0d.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 00:e0:4c:b8:5b:fd
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ip=47.18.1.25 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:17 ioport:c800(size=256) memory:ec006000-ec0060ff memory:40010000-4001ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: nForce3 AGP Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             version: a4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master
             resources: memory:e8000000-eaffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: NV43 [GeForce 6600 GT]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=32 maxlatency=1 mingnt=5
                resources: irq:16 memory:e8000000-e8ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e9000000-e9ffffff memory:c0000-dffff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k8temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0700
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0400
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=parport_pc
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNPb006
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=mpu401
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNPb02f
          physical id: b
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=ns558
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@4
       logical name: scsi4
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
```

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.3 present.
34 structures occupying 938 bytes.
Table at 0x000F0000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Phoenix Technologies, LTD
    Version: 6.00 PG
    Release Date: 09/13/2003
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 512 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        APM is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        AGP is supported
        LS-120 boot is supported
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 25 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer:  
    Product Name:  
    Version:  
    Serial Number:  
    UUID: Not Present
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer:  
    Product Name: nForce
    Version:  
    Serial Number:  

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 17 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer:  
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Boot-up State: Unknown
    Power Supply State: Unknown
    Thermal State: Unknown
    Security Status: Unknown
    OEM Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: Socket A
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Duron
    Manufacturer: AMD
    ID: 48 0F 00 00 FF FB 8B 07
    Signature: Family 15, Model 4, Stepping 8
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
    Version: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3200+
    Voltage: 1.4 V
    External Clock: 201 MHz
    Max Speed: 500 MHz
    Current Speed: 2010 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0008
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0009
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 20 bytes
Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: 8-bit Parity
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 32 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 64 MB
    Supported Speeds:
        70 ns
        60 ns
    Supported Memory Types:
        Standard
        EDO
    Memory Module Voltage: 5.0 V
    Associated Memory Slots: 2
        0x0006
        0x0007
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities: None

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: A0
    Bank Connections: 0 1
    Current Speed: 10 ns
    Type: Other
    Installed Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: A1
    Bank Connections: 2 3
    Current Speed: 10 ns
    Type: Other
    Installed Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: Internal Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 128 kB
    Maximum Size: 128 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Unknown
    System Type: Unknown
    Associativity: Unknown

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: External Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 1024 kB
    Maximum Size: 1024 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Unknown
    System Type: Unknown
    Associativity: Unknown

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: PRIMARY IDE
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: SECONDARY IDE
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: FDD
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Floppy
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: 8251 FIFO Compatible

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: COM1
    Internal Connector Type: 9 Pin Dual Inline (pin 10 cut)
    External Reference Designator:  
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16450 Compatible

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: COM2
    Internal Connector Type: 9 Pin Dual Inline (pin 10 cut)
    External Reference Designator:  
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16450 Compatible

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: LPT1
    Internal Connector Type: DB-25 female
    External Reference Designator:  
    External Connector Type: DB-25 female
    Port Type: Parallel Port ECP/EPP

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Keyboard
    Internal Connector Type: PS/2
    External Reference Designator:  
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: PS/2 Mouse
    Internal Connector Type: PS/2
    External Reference Designator:  
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Not Specified
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB0
    External Connector Type: Other
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI0
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI1
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI2
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI3
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI4
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 5
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: AGP
    Type: 32-bit AGP
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 88
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 3
        n|US|iso8859-1
        n|US|iso8859-1
        r|CA|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: n|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 1 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A0
    Bank Locator: Bank0/1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: None
    Serial Number: None
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: None

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1
    Bank Locator: Bank2/3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: None
    Serial Number: None
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: None

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 2 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x001A
    Partition Width: 1

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0003FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x001B
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x001D
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00040000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x001C
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x001D
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 32, 11 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Idea # 1

```
CPU: Intel Core i5-12600K 3.7 GHz 10-Core Processor  ($278.95 @ Amazon) 
CPU Cooler: *Noctua NH-L9i-17xx chromax.black 33.84 CFM CPU Cooler  ($54.95 @ Amazon) 
    OR Noctua NH-L9x65 33.84 CFM CPU Cooler @ $59.85
    OR Noctua NH-L9x65
Motherboard: MSI MPG Z690 CARBON WIFI ATX LGA1700 Motherboard  ($349.99 @ Amazon) 
Memory: Kingston FURY Beast 8 GB (1 x 8 GB) DDR5-5200 CL40 Memory  ($56.37 @ Amazon) 
Memory: Kingston FURY Beast 8 GB (1 x 8 GB) DDR5-5200 CL40 Memory  ($56.37 @ Amazon) 
Storage: Samsung 980 500 GB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive  ($54.99 @ Amazon) 
Storage: Seagate Barracuda Compute 8 TB 3.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive  ($129.99 @ Amazon) 
Video Card: MSI GeForce GTX 1650 G6 4 GB D6 VENTUS XS OC Video Card 
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 32/64-bit  ($269.99 @ Amazon) 
Total: $1251.60
```

Idea 2:

```
CPU: Intel Core i3-12100F 3.3 GHz Quad-Core Processor  ($121.00 @ Amazon) 
CPU Cooler: Noctua NH-U12S redux 70.75 CFM CPU Cooler  ($49.95 @ Amazon) 
Motherboard: ASRock B660 Pro RS ATX LGA1700 Motherboard  ($127.98 @ Amazon) 
Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws V 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16 Memory  ($56.99 @ Amazon) 
Storage: Samsung 980 500 GB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive  ($54.99 @ Amazon) 
Storage: Seagate Barracuda Compute 8 TB 3.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive  ($129.99 @ Amazon) 
Video Card: MSI GeForce GTX 1650 G6 4 GB D6 VENTUS XS OC Video Card 
Power Supply: EVGA SuperNOVA 650 650 W 80+ Platinum Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply  ($89.99 @ Amazon) 
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 32/64-bit  ($229.99 @ Amazon) 
Total: $860.88
```

Open for more ideas!

Comment: I would just buy a new computer. Maybe you can reuse the case if it's ATX (and not BTX) and the PSU if your next PC is gonna be low power.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the requirements?

Comment: @Irsu85: I would like to do light photo and video editing, browse the web and would need 8 TB of storage. SSD to boot Wndows 10/11. Budget Build. I would add the parts list to kick us off and would love to hear better ideas.

Comment: Then option 2 is better, except I reccommend saving the $229 for MS Windows and instead get the I5 12600K (and if you wonder what OS you should use then, I use Linux for the same things and it's amazing)

Comment: should be cheaper and faster in total

Comment: @Irsu85 Love the recommendation! I am a fanboy myself, but it is not for me. I sure would run this by them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for Processor and Mobo combo which isn't 100% upgrade friendly but allows me to save about $200 and I am not planning to keep upgrading this build to newest and latest. I also picked open box power supply in favor of better quality and keeping my final price low. Video card is not the top off line but, it has just enough cores for my light video editing.

Pros:

- Low price point
- Modest build

Cons:

- A little slower video card
- Would have to change mother board and also RAM upgrading to 12th gen or newer CPU

Specs:

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-11700K 3.6 GHz 8-Core Processor
CPU Cooler: Noctua NH-U12S 55 CFM CPU Cooler
Motherboard: Asus Prime Z590-P WiFi ATX LGA1200 Motherboard
Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws V 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16 Memory
Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws V 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16 Memory
Storage: Samsung 980 500 GB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive
Storage: Seagate Barracuda Compute 8 TB 3.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive  
Video Card: Asus GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4 GB Phoenix Video Card
Power Supply: PowerSpec PS 750BSM 750 W 80+ Bronze Certified Semi-modular ATX Power Supply

Total: $889.80
```